# What is the basic difference between System.Collections.Generic.List and System.Linq.IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

what is the basic difference between System.Linq.IQueryable and System.Collections.Generic.List which one is faster and when to use what?

Comment: Difference is they are *Apples and oranges*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IQueryable<T>` is an `interface` which abstracts some type of query. This query can be executed (by iterating over the query), but you have to use `ToList<T>` to convert (the results of) the query into a list.

A `List<T>` is just a list which can contain some objects. Ready for you to be retrieved when you need them.